# read access permissions from an array

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

the user's permissions come in an array, as I do to validate whether or not he has access by iterating the arrat

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean { 

   const expectedPermission = route.data.expectedPermission;
   const token= localStorage.getItem("Token")
   const tokenPayload = decode(token);
   const role=tokenPayload['https://menu-api.demo.com/roles'][0];
   console.log(route);
   const permissions=["create:user", "delete:user", "read:user"]
     if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated() || permissions !== expectedPermission) {
       this.router.navigate(['external-api']);
         return false;
     }

   return true;
 }
```

---

```
{
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [RoleGuard], 
    data: { 
      expectedPermission: 'read:user'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where's the array?

Comment: Sorry I missed that, I just edited @KurtHamilton

Answer (score 1):

You need to see if the `expectedPermission` exists in the `permissions` array.

There are several ways of doing this. If the strings are guaranteed to be exact matches (the same case), then you can use the `includes` array function.

```
if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated() || !permissions.includes(expectedPermission)) {
  // user doesn't have permission
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are comparing the references of the arrays, which is probably not what you want.

You should check if all of the `expectedPermissions` exists in `permissions`. This can be accomplished by combining `every` and `includes` function:

```
if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated() || !expectedPermission.every(expectedPermission => permissions.includes(expectedPermission))) {
 //no permission
}
```

Every loops over the `expectedPermissions` array and only returns true if the given predicate is true for every item. The predicate we use is to check if the item is included in the permissions array.

Comment: `expectedPermission` is a string

Comment: Oh, my bad. I kind of automatically thought of an array. But your are totally right, I should have read the question better.  Well then your answer is the correct one.

Comment: Easy to be misled by the `permissions !== expectedPermission` expression in the question